# .lib не является приложением win32

Tags: c++, winapi, static, library

В одном решении у меня находятся два приложения: Статическая библиотека и Консольное приложение. Собрал библиотеку, добавил в консольное приложение, при запуске **консольного приложения** выходит ошибка:

> Не удаётся запустить программу `"C:\...\.lib"`
>
> `C:\...\.lib` не является допустимым приложением win32

Использую ОС `Windows 10 x64`

Comment: Все правильно. lib-файлы не являются PE-файлами. "добавил в консольное приложение" - это как?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов "добавил в консольное приложение": пользовался официальной инструкцией https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235627.aspx#BKMK_UseLibInApp

Comment: Там вроде про C#, а у вас плюсы...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не, там про C++. Я вроде понял почему ошибка, не собрал решение, но пока не уверен, пока не решу все ошибки

Answer (score 2):

1. Вместо нажатия на F5, что запускала проект, стоило собрать проект.
2. Solution1 -> Свойства -> Общие свойства -> Запускаемый проект -> выставить один запускаемый проект на то самое консольное приложение

Comment: При надлежащей настройке по F5 оно все должно собираться.

Comment: @VTT Оно всё и собирается, но у меня стояло в настройках приложение для запуска .lib

Answer (score 1):

Для начала стоит настроить IDE:

- открываем Опции `Main menu` → `Tools` → `Options`
- идем в настройки сборки и запуска `Project and solutions` → `Build and Run`
- выставляем галочку `Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run`
- в выпадающем списке `On Run, when projects are out of date` выбираем пункт `Always build`
- в выпадающем списке `On Run, when build or deployment errors occur` выбираем пункт `Do not launch`

Затем в проекте следует добавить библиотеку в качестве зависимости для консольного проекта, выбрав в контекстном меню для проекта пункт `Add` → `Referece`.

Затем указать консольный проект в качестве стартового: выбрав в контекстном меню для проекта пункт `Set as StartUp project`.

Теперь при нажатии F5 проекты будут пересобраны (при наличии изменений) и запушен консольный проект.